# meaning of "start a class"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I'm studying Spanish. I started classes in December.

I can roughly presume that the second sentence means "I started to take classes in December" because of the first sentence.

But can the second sentence also mean "I started to teach classes" depending on context?

Comment: If you are studying Spanish, I would hope not to have you as a teacher of it in one of my classes . . . (On the other hand, I suppose that if you are studying *advanced* Spanish, it might be okay if you were a teacher of *introductory* Spanish.) But if the meaning in the second sentence deviates from that in the first, it's normally best to signal that by adding *teaching*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - I graduated with a degree in Spanish Education in October. I started classes in December.
> - I have devised a new structure for computer training. I started classes in December.

In both cases the context makes it clear that the speaker is teaching classes, not taking them. But in the absence of such context "I started classes" usually means taking them, that is as a student, not as a teacher.